# error caught during app initialization Error: ambiguous indirect export: XMarkIcon

Tags: tailwind-css, nuxtjs3, heroicons

Nuxi 3.2.3
Nuxt 3.2.3 with Nitro 2.2.3
tailwindcss 3.2.7

import { Bars3Icon, MagnifyingGlassIcon, ShoppingBagIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/vue/24/outline'

I try to reinstall @heroicons/vue